# Relative loss of power and length of signal

Tags: power-spectral-density, butterworth

I have EEG signal data from a single channel for 150 similar events (epochs), each spanning 11s which might be accessed from [here](https://ufile.io/dtzk809c).

I ran the following code block in MATLAB to remove line noise at 60 Hz using a Butterworth order-4 filter and then, plotted PSD for increasing time durations from t=100 ms to t=3000 ms (always starting from t=0):

```matlab
% Manually load Raw_Feed which is EEG data from a single channel for 150 epochs of 11s each %

% Declare vars
start_duration = 100;
end_duration = 3000;
interval = 100;
samprate = 1000;
desired_frame_rate = 2;

% De-noise
d = designfilt('bandstopiir','FilterOrder',4,'HalfPowerFrequency1',59,'HalfPowerFrequency2',61, 'DesignMethod','butter','SampleRate',1000); %Design BW-4 filter for line noise
Denoised_out = filtfilt(d, Raw_feed); % Apply filter
Denoised_out = reshape(Denoised_out, [1, size(Denoised_out)]); %Add a suprious channel dimension for Spectopo function

% Get video params
num_frames = (end_duration - start_duration) / interval + 1;
frame_interval = 1 / desired_frame_rate;

% Create a video object
video = VideoWriter('Movie_1.avi');
video.FrameRate = desired_frame_rate;
open(video);

% Loop through the samples, create frames, and write to video
for sample = start_duration:interval:end_duration
    % Spectopo is part of EEGLAB - install the toolbox from https://sccn.ucsd.edu/eeglab/download.php
    % The particular code can be accessed at https://github.com/sccn/eeglab/blob/develop/functions/sigprocfunc/spectopo.m 
    
    % Generate the PSD plot
    [~, ~, ~, ~, ~] = spectopo(Denoised_out(:, 1:sample, :), sample, samprate);
    text(0.5, 0.8, sprintf('Time duration: %d ms', sample), 'Units', 'normalized', 'Color', 'black', 'FontSize', 12);
    
    % Capture the current plot as a frame
    frame = getframe(gcf);

    % Write the frame to the video
    writeVideo(video, frame);

    % Close the current figure to clear it for the next plot
    close(gcf);

    % Pause to achieve the desired frame rate
    pause(frame_interval);
end

% Close the video file
close(video);
```

The movie which can be accessed [here](https://imgur.com/a/UHwBa0C) shows an interesting trend — the lengthier the duration is, the more the loss of power at 60Hz gets! That is, the notch at 60Hz in the curve gets progressively deeper from X=100ms to X=1000ms before stabilizing.

I wonder what might be the cause. Some hints will be welcome.

Comment: Are you applying the notch filter at 50 or 60Hz? You say 50hz but then mention what happens at 60hz…

Comment: Are the parameters for Welch’s method (segment length, overlap, etc) the same regardless of the length of X?

Comment: @Jdip All params remain same for each PSD. 50/60 was an inadvertent mixup; fixed.

Comment: I will be adding a minimum reproducible code in a short while.

Answer (score 1):

What you observe there is the transient behaviour of the Butterworth filter, specifically the ["ringing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_(signal)) artifact.

Once the system is in steady state, the ringing will  disappear. It will, however, reappear at the next discontinuity.

Its frequency is near the corner frequency of the filter. If it bothers you, choose another filter design. But then you will have to live with a similar phenomenon in the frequency domain. There will always be the tradeoff between maximal spectral flatness and the filter being well behaved in the time domain.

Comment: But the PSD is computed on the signal **post-filtering**, not on each segment, wouldn’t this discard this reasoning?

Comment: There is only 3s of signal. As far as I understood, the PSD was calculated on segments of different lengths, but always with the same starting point $n=0$. So the ringing effect would be less and less prominent, the longer the segment, which seems to be exactly what AvadaMouse describes.

Comment: Aha, I think you’re correct.

Comment: @Max I have added an MRCE.

Comment: Even with the new information the answer is still the same. Transient behaviour of the filter.

Comment: How is it the same? The filter is applied to the whole data at once.

Comment: Well, in a sense, it is not. The data is passed sample by sample through the IIR filter, even when it's just one line of code. This filter needs a certain time to reach steady state. Until then, transient behaviour is predominant.

Comment: What Max is suggesting is that if you grab a small segment, of length start_duration for example but **from a steady state portion** such as the middle of the filtered signal, you should see a steeper response. I do think lower frequency resolution for smaller segments also plays a role here, though.